# Is there a way to plug into the IE browser on WP7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want the user to be able to hover a link, select my app and IE will open my app and pass the url. Is there something like this in IE for WP7? If not, can I embed IE in my app and have a popup show when I hover on a url?

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to add plugins or extensions to the native browser, but you are able to embed the 
[WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431797%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) into your application. You could then potentially use the [InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402838%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) method to add whatever css/javascript popup you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can embed a browser inside your application. Here's an example application that shows how to create your own web browser directly inside of a WP7 app:

[How To Create Your First Silverlight Application - WebBrowser Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402526%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

This is also another interesting link on creating an entire website withing your application and storing it in isolated storage:

[Loading a Local HTML FIle](http://phone7.wordpress.com/2010/08/08/loading-a-local-html-file-in-the-webbrowser-control/)